# iTunes not showing cover art

Tags: c#, itunes, taglib-sharp

I'm using the Spotify API to fetch the cover for a specific song. I'm settings this cover to the song as shown here:

```
using (var file = TagLib.File.Create(SavePath))
{
    file.Tag.Title = information.Name;
    file.Tag.Performers = new[] {information.Artist};
    file.Tag.Album = information.Album;

    if (information.Artwork != null)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
            var data = client.DownloadData(information.Artwork.Url);

            file.Tag.Pictures = new IPicture[]
            {
                new Picture
                {
                    Data = new ByteVector(data),
                    Type = PictureType.FrontCover,
                    Description = "Cover"
                }
            };
        }
    }

    file.Save();       
}
```

This code works fine and the artwork is shown properly in Windows Explorer and in Groove too.

However when importing the song to iTunes the cover is not loaded. Instead the default "cover" ist shown.

Let's take for instance this song here:

ATOM - Rocket
The cover url is https://i.scdn.co/image/897abec6f8cbf91392f8fafdb88a70d431280912

In the explorer the cover is shown:
[image]

In Groove you can see it too:
[image]

But in iTunes it is not displayed:
[image]

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the database or anything like that? I suppose applications use caching for the album arts, so, that might help. If it doesn't, try setting the cover art without specifying the type.